# How to upload multiple images in codigniter. Please any body shere code

Tags: upload

How to upload multiple images in code ignite r. Please any body shear code .
this is my code to upload a file which is written in a controller.Please any body suggest what is wrong with this code.

```
function do_upload_slider()
   {
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;
    echo $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {

        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    



    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    $this->upload->do_upload_slider();


    }

}
private function set_upload_options()
{   
//  upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/slider/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']      = '2048000';
    $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;


    return $config;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one.it may be help you
uploadform_view.php.



<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('imageupload/doupload');?>
<input name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple="" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
<?php echo form_close() ?>
</body>
</html>

Create A New Controller: controllers/imageupload.php 


     class Imageupload extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('imageupload_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }
    function doupload() {
    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
    }
    $names= implode(',', $name_array);
    /* $this->load->database();
    $db_data = array('id'=> NULL,
    'name'=> $names);
    $this->db->insert('testtable',$db_data);
    */ print_r($names);
    }
    }
```

And that is it. Customize it to your needs, the basics are there already. And good luck!